# Suspend/Wakeup in Beagleboard using Angstrom

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboard

I want to suspend and resume my `Beagleboard C4`.

I checked out the latest Angstrom kernel using,

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tmlind/linux-omap-2.6.git linux-omap-2.6
```

But the kernel is not booting properly. It is stuck at

```
[    4.755645] EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
[    4.991027] EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
[    4.999023] VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    5.006652] Freeing init memory: 304K
[    6.316253] EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p2): using internal journal
```

Has anyone resolved this issue?

I compiled the kernel directly on the beagleboard. Same result.
I compiled the kernel using toolchain. Same result.

Is it something related to the u-boot/File system?